# Hide MediaPlayer Controls ( Microsoft Media Platform Player Framework )

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, mmppf

I´m using the MMP:PF in a c#/xaml application and 
provide my own control elements to handle the player.

Thats why i would like to hide/disable its own native controls that appear on the bottom. 
( And in the middle of the screen on screenshot, this one´s just using a theme )

Does anybody know how to do that? I didnt manage to find a property for that.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `MediaPlayer`'s reference, `IsTimeLineVisible`, `IsPlayPauseVisible`, `IsPositionVisible`, `IsStopVisible` and many other visibility properties available. so you can set them to false. take a look at the [MediaPlayer Properties](http://smf.blob.core.windows.net/docs/win8/xaml/api/Index.html)

Comment: Thank you very, i should look more closely next time!

Answer (score 7):

Use like this:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "None";
```

Answer (score 5):

The magic property to keep players controls from showing up at all:

```
InteractiveActivationMode="None"
```

Comment: Excellent.  And this one doesn't cause the player to hide other controls.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution to HichemC's answer: you can change the Player control template.

Using Blend, it's not very hard, and it gives you a lot of control. For instance, you can hook your controls on the Player's states (VSM) and be sure your controls are correctly synchronized with the player's internal state.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide/show all controls at once:

```
_player.IsInteractive = true/false;
```

Here´s an screenshot of the decompiled MediaPlayer.cs for those saying the property does not exists.

[image]

Comment: IsInteractive does not exist as a property, atleast not in my VS 2017

Comment: I don't see this property at all.  Nor the others mentioned above (IsTimeLineVisible, IsPlayPauseVisible, IsPositionVisible, IsStopVisible)

Comment: Guys, before you downvote something, make sure your statement is true. The property is there if you install Microsoft Player framework vsix extension from https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=playerframework.

Answer (score -1):

I am responsible for the MMPPF at Microsoft and am happy to help wi any questions. I concur with the suggestions here. Though I love this site, we don't monitor it very heavily for MMPPF support questions. If you do need answers from us, the support page on the CodePlex project site is monitored by my team on a daily basis and they're pretty quick to respond. Don't let that deter you from using this forum - I'm just suggesting that our project site is a better way to get answers directly from the developers, if needed.

I hope your app did well.

Mike Downey
miked --at--- microsoft.com

Comment: Sure would like if you provided a non-hackish way to tell the player to stay at the last frame when finished playing, instead of going back to the first frame.